# Does changing the app's "Display name" invalidate access tokens?

Tags: facebook-authentication, facebook-access-token

If I change my app's "Display name", will users have to grant permissions again, or will it continue working for current users as is?

I did try this with a dummy app with just one user - no reauthorizing needed. But I'd like to be sure that my other app with many more users will behave the same.

Answer (score 1):

No, your users won’t have to authorize again. Authorization and permissions are linked to the app id, not the name that’s displayed.